# Can't comment html with shortcut vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

The shortcut "Ctrl + /"

When I use it, it writes this: 
**{% comment %}** html line  **{% endcomment %}**
instead of

**< !--** commented html line **-->**

How to solve this. I woke up this morning and this happened. I don't know what can  cause it.

I have installed sublime keymap extension

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f42bc.png)

Comment: Looks like you are using some templating engine. Could you please add a screenshot ? It will be helpful.

Comment: Try changing the `language` in the status bar to `HTML`, it's in the bottom right.

Comment: I solve the problem by pressing on the HTML, in the bottom right. Then  an option "auto detect" appeared, and it worked. Thanks for the support!

Comment: am also facing same issue i have selected auto detect option but still the same any idea?Thanks!